# Laravel 7 Auth No HomeController

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm moving to Laravel 7 from 5 and using the new auth scaffolding. Not migrating an existing project - just migrating to using the updated version. And I can not get it to generate a home controller.  All of the auth controllers generate just fine.

My Steps:

Make a new project: `laravel new laravelAuth`

cd into the project: `cd laravelAuth`

Require the lavavel/ui package: `composer require laravel/ui --dev`

Run the artisan ui command: `php artisan ui vue --auth`

Install and compile: `npm install && npm run dev`

After I attempt to create an account I get the error:
`Target class [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController] does not exist.`

And it's right, there is no HomeController. Any ideas of what to check would be helpful. I'm using Laravel version 7.9.2

Comment: Try installing Laravel from composer directly: `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel my-website`. That installer is a mess.

Comment: Thanks for the idea... but alas, no dice. Everything runs but no HomeController. I, of course, could make my own but that seems to be against the point of the whole instant-Auth thing.

Comment: Is the only missing file ?

Comment: Yes the only missing file is the HomeController... all the Auth controllers are made correctly.

Comment: Indeed, the file is neither created for me. I think this commit broke it https://github.com/laravel/ui/commit/88a744d7ad1301c7836f52968cb3607cd760e078 Perhaps you could submit an issue

Comment: This is happening after login?

Comment: By the way, I would not recommend to add `--dev` since the AuthControllers depends from traits nor interface from the package

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier thanks for finding that commit. And yes --dev, you are correct... I was just doing that for my tests. Out of habit I guess.

Comment: Well, same here - have to create the controller manually I guess after the install. `php artisan make:controller HomeController` should do the trick and add the `public function index()`

Comment: Ok well for those who come after us, the patch seems to be to make your own HomeController for now. Thanks Christophe.

Comment: please check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61503214/4258328 for a quick fix

Comment: I did a pull request https://github.com/laravel/ui/pull/100 hopefully it will be fixed shortly

Comment: Thanks, @ClémentBaconnier, you went faster than me 

Answer (score 2):

It just has been fixed with `laravel/ui` version 2.0.3

https://github.com/laravel/ui/pull/100

You can make `composer update` if necessary

Answer (score 1):

As of now, it looks like this [commit](https://github.com/laravel/ui/commit/88a744d7ad1301c7836f52968cb3607cd760e078) is stopping the creation of the HomeController in Laravel/ui.

The workaround is to make your own HomeController:
`php artisan make:controller HomeController`

Here is what to put in your home controller after you make it:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
}
```