# FIXED AFTER I REPORTED THE BUG - laravel new project --auth doesn't create HomeController.php

Tags: laravel, authentication, controller

I have created a new laravel project with --auth, but HomeController hasn't been created. I have tried with composer require laravel/ui and php artisan ui vue --auth in an existing project and I encounter the same problem. Any solutions? I know I coould create it manually, but it is annoying. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The HomeController is not being created at the time of writing 29-Apr-2020
a quick workaround is to create it manually:

```
php artisan make:controller HomeController
```

and then fill it with the following code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Cristophe

Comment: No problem - if this solves your problem don't forget to accept the asnwer

Answer (score 1):

It was a bug that was [fixed](https://github.com/laravel/ui/pull/100) by the Laravel staff in Laravel UI version 2.0.3.

[image: bug fixed by official staff]